# c# application with mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, web-hosting

I'm developing C# application that interact with MySQL database hosted on free hostingwebsite:

```
private void Initialize()
{
    server = "ex.exexexex.com:3306";
    database = "1_dotnet";
    uid = "1_dotnet";
    password = "********";
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}

private bool OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

But there is an error:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: Can you post your exception detail rather than just the message?

Comment: Message=Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
  Source=MySql.Data
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Number=1042

Comment: If you google for `mysql error 1024` it seems that this is due to not being able to connect to the server for various reasons (likely to be host name resolution)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the connection string settings in your web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="strConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DATABASE_IP_OR_DOMAIN;userid=MYSQL_LOGIN;password=MYSQL_PASSWORD;database=DATABASE_NAME;Connection Lifetime=0;Connect Timeout=300;pooling='true';Max Pool Size=200" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then in your C# code you can reference your database connection like this

```
MySqlConnection objConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConnection"].ConnectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd = default(MySqlCommand);
objConnection.Open();
```

Comment: How in my web.config ??!
it's a C# app. how can I use this tags !?

Comment: Are you building a web site?  If so you will have to use ASP.Net as that is the only kind of web site you can use C# in.  In every ASP.Net web app there is a web.config file in the root of the project.  If you are building a console or windows app you would have an app.config

Comment: in that case you can use app.config.